# Переключиться между ветками в gitlab ci (job)

Tags: git, gitlab, git-branch, gitlab-ci

Изучаю gitlab ci/cd, условно говоря есть 2 ветки master и Test, есть нисходящий pipeline который находится в master ветке.

```
stages:
    - tst

TEST:
    stage: tst
    when: manual
    trigger:
        include:
            - project: '1GODLIKE1/commit'
              ref: 'Test'
              file: '.gitlab-ci.yml'
```

Он запускает ветку Test, но когда я хочу запустить файл который лежит в этой ветке выдает ошибку, что "Нет такого файла". Вот как выглядит pipeline в ветке Test.

```
stages:
    - tst
    
TEST:
    stage: tst
    when: manual
    tags:
        - tstBuild
    script:
        - source ~/venv/bin/activate
        - python ./main.py
```

И так есть несколько вопросов, почему так происходит ?
И могу ли при downstream pipeline, за одно и переключится на другую ветку, если да, то как это сделать ?
А если такой возможности нет, то как лучше поступить ?
Может быть у кого то есть решение которое он уже использовал ?
P.S. в документации к gitlab, не нашел как это можно было бы сделать. Пробовал использовать "git checkout Test", он не работает.